# Jean Michel Jarre songs with lyrics

Tags: lyrics, electronic-music

Jean michel jarre is one of my favorite New Age performers.
I love lot of his  instrumental track but I wander if there are also his good songs with lyrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Revolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_(Jean-Michel_Jarre_album)) has some lyrics but not really in the same way as more conventional songs.

Here are some credits:

- Jean-Michel Jarre – Synclavier, Roland D-50, Fairlight CMI, Synthex, EMS Synthi AKS, OSC OSCar, EMS Vocoder, Dynacord ADD1, Cristal Baschet, Akai MPC60, drums programming, percussions, **computer vocals on "Revolutions"**
- Mireille Pombo – vocal chorus on "September"
- The Bruno Rossignol Choir, directed by Bruno Rossignol – choir on "Industrial Revolution", "London Kid" and "The Emigrant"
- Female choir from Mali, directed by Sori Bamba – choir on "September"

Answer (score 3):

His last couple of albums, Electronica Volumes 1 and 2, feature several songs with sung lyrics.

These are collaborative works, the leit motif of the albums being that each track is a collaboration with a notable electronic or EDM musician, and several other people are credited as co-composers.

But the Jarre style is clearly present, so I guess we can say there is Jarre music with sung lyrics. I couldn't find explicit lyric authorship attribution, so I don't know if Jarre penned some or all of the lyrics himself.

I don't know all his discography in detail, so I don't know if there are other instances of songs with lyrics in his discography, but I don't recall any.